# Can we perform action after click event completion in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have written this code to click an anchor tag -

```
$('main.core-rail').querySelector('a[data-control-name=contact_see_more]').click();
var ContactDocument = $('#artdeco-modal-outlet');
```

I want to run this 2nd line of code after click event completion not immediate. could you please help me to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is it that runs that you want to wait for the completion of? Does `.click()` trigger an asynchronous function or something? The next line after the `.click()` will already run after the event completes (the event will have propagated to the root element by the time the second line runs)

Answer (score 1):

You can use click event callback function which is run once click event is completed.

```
$('main.core-rail').querySelector('a[data-control-name=contact_see_more]').click(function() {
  var ContactDocument = $('#artdeco-modal-outlet'); 
});
```